# Fit second text box to another text boxes path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, page-layout

I'm working with two languages (english and arabic) and I want to keep the text boxes separate so that the styles do not clash.

I have a unique text box shape for the english as it covers the whole product.

I am trying to find a way to make a second text box take the shape of the first box, more specifically the shape of a segment of the first box.

Any ideas and or answers would be greatly appreciated.

ETA:
yes here is an image of the shape. imgur.com/a/bs6b8 I am using two languages and I want to be able to place a second text box inside the shape of the first text box. I don't want the languages to mingle because it can easily screw everything up. I want to be able make a second text box and make its border take the shape of the other text box. My work around so far is to duplicate the shape but then I have to try and move the second text into the appropriate place instead of just placing it where I want. –

Comment: It's not immediately clear to me where you're getting stuck. You could improve your question by making an [edit] and including screenshots. Would duplicating the existing text box work?

Comment: Did you ask this question under a different name recently?  I swear I've seen this identical question on the site in the past week or two, but can't find it now.

Comment: yes here is an image of the shape.
http://imgur.com/a/bs6b8

I am using two languages and I want to be able to place a second text box inside the shape of the first text box. I don't want the languages to mingle because it can easily screw everything up.

I want to be able make a second text box and make its border take the shape of the other text box. My work around so far is to duplicate the shape but then I have to try and move the second text into the appropriate place instead of just placing it where I want.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understand of the issue, it sounds like you need to create a constant shape and then just have versions of it with different text. If that is correct, then <kbd>Type > Convert to Area Type</kbd> should help you make the constant shape.